# undefined method `method' for "String":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently getting this error:

> undefined method `street_address' for "Not Set":String

My goal is to handle an error that occurs when a user's address comes back nil.

Here's the code with where the error occurs:

```
def address
    if params[formatted_address["address"]].nil?
      address = ''
      street_address = ''
      country = ''
      region = ''
      city = ''
      zip = ''
    else
      address = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(formatted_address["address"])
      street_address = address["street_address"]
      country = address["country"]
      region = address["region"]
      city = address["locality"]
      zip = address["postal_code"]
    end   
  end

  info do
    {
      name: user_info.name,
      email: user_info.email,
      nickname: user_info.preferred_username,
      first_name: user_info.given_name,
      last_name: user_info.family_name,
      gender: user_info.gender,
      phone: user_info.phone_number,
      birthdate: user_info.birthdate,
      street_address: address.street_address, <-- error occurs here
      country: address.country,
      region: address.region,
      city: address.city,
      zip: address.zip,
      urls: { website: user_info.website }
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

in the else statement i just created a replica JSON with the values that i wanted to come back

```
def address
        if formatted_address["address"].nil?
          address = JSON.parse('{
            "street_address": "",
            "country": "",
            "region": "",
            "locality": "",
            "postal_code": ""
            }')
        else
          address = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(formatted_address["address"])
        end
      end

  info do
    {
      name: user_info.name,
      email: user_info.email,
      nickname: user_info.preferred_username,
      first_name: user_info.given_name,
      last_name: user_info.family_name,
      gender: user_info.gender,
      phone: user_info.phone_number,
      birthdate: user_info.birthdate,
      street_address: address["street_address"],
      country: address["country"],
      region: address["region"],
      city: address["locality"],
      zip: address["postal_code"],
      urls: { website: user_info.website }
    }
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to save the blank spaces in address fields in case of blank address parameters, then you should set defaults to ' ' in the migration/table.